# How do I return results for each day until a set limit is reached?

Tags: c#, pagination, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Using c# and Entity Framework, I want to return results by day created until a specified limit is reached. To return for just the past day I have:

```
blogs.Where(a => a.Created >= DateTime.Now.Date);
```

Where blogs is of type `IEnumerable<Blog>`. But I want to make it so that it keeps searching back one day at a time until I reach 10 results, and then to also know what date was reached (or something similar to this).

Just to explain, this is for part of an infinite scroll on a page, and I want the pages to be by date ranges, rather than just taking the next 10. This will help to prevent any issues with a new blog being entered while a user is scrolling down the list.

Not really sure how to proceed with this, so any suggestions/ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify it's 10 results I'm looking for not 10 days worth. Also, it doesn't have to be exactly 10 results. Maybe 10 should be the minimum amount. I would make each page a day, but a day may not have any results, or it could have many. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you don't want to display 10 blogs per page but all blogs that have been created on 10 days. Then you could try this query:

```
int page = 1;         // the page you want to display, 1, 2, 3, ...
int daysPerPage = 10;

List<Blog> result = blogs
    .GroupBy(b => b.Created.Date)      // group blogs by day
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)     // sort the day groups descending by day
    .Skip((page - 1) * daysPerPage)    // skip the pages before requested page
    .Take(daysPerPage)                 // take the next 10 day groups
    .SelectMany(g => g)                // get all blogs of 10 days in flat list
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Created) // sort blogs descending by blog date+time
    .ToList();                         // make a list with the result
```

The oldest date that is displayed can be found with:

```
DateTime? oldestDate = result
    .Select(b => (DateTime?)b.Created.Date)
    .LastOrDefault();
```

(The nullable stuff is only here to deal with the case that `result` is empty. `oldestDate` would be `null` then.)

If you want this as a database query, i.e. `blogs` is actually a `DbSet<Blog>` like `context.Blogs`, you probably have to rewrite it a bit because `DateTime.Date` is not supported with LINQ-to-Entities:

```
List<Blog> result = context.Blogs
    .GroupBy(b => new { b.Created.Year, b.Created.Month, b.Created.Day })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.Year)
    .ThenByDescending(g => g.Key.Month)
    .ThenByDescending(g => g.Key.Day)
    .Skip((page - 1) * daysPerPage)
    .Take(daysPerPage)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Created)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's the number of posts I need, not days. There's no guarantee that the past 10 days would have any blogs to return, however going back one more day could have 9. So what I want is to keep searching each day until I have some results to display.

Comment: @AndrewPolland: If there is no blog on a day this day would not count to the 10 days because there is no group (`GroupBy`) for this day. Or in other words: the 10 days that are extracted in the query above all have *at least 1 blog*. So, you get always a minimum of 10 blogs. However, if each of the 10 days would have for example 5 blogs you would get 50 blogs extracted.

Comment: Sorry. To be honest I didn't properly read your answer after I read the first line which sounded like you'd got the wrong idea. Now I've looked at it properly I can see you have pretty much given me the answer I required. Thanks, and sorry for not reading it properly.

Answer (score 3):

`IEnumerable<T>.Take(int count)` will limit the number of results returned by a provided count.

Try this:

```
// First, Limit by 10
var result = blogs
   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Created)
   .Where(a => a.Created >= DateTime.Now.Date).Take(10);

// Get last max date:
var lastDate = result.Max(a => a.Created);

// Subsequent, Limit by 10
var subsequentResult = blogs
   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Created)
   .Where(a => a.Created >= lastDate).Take(10);

lastDate = subsequentResult.Max(a => a.Created);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OrderBy** to sort records by day and by using Take() which takes int parameter, you cant limit the records like this:

```
blogs.OrderBy(a=>a.Created).Where(a => a.Created >= DateTime.Now.Date).Take(10);
```

Comment: hmm, right,, group by will not do the job in this scenario.:/

Comment: You actually almost had it and you certainly pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for based on some ideas from the answers. It's not an exact match for the question I asked, but it solves the problem I outlined.

```
int page = 1;
int NumOfDays = 3;
blogs = blogs.GroupBy(a => a.Created.Date).Skip((page - 1) * NumOfDays).Take(NumOfDays).SelectMany(a=>a.Select(b=>b));
```

This will group by the date then take 3 days worth of dates that actually have content for each page loaded. This solves the main problem of ensuring each page returns some blogs, each page contains all the blogs for the days it covers and it allows me to get the next page easily.

Thanks everyone who answered.